# Unable to execute shell scripts on cygwin(mintty terminal) using Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins-pipeline, cygwin

Unable to execute shell scripts on Cygwin(mintty terminal) using Jenkins pipeline but I can able to execute same scripts directly on Cygwin(mintty terminal), cygwin is installed on jenkins windows agent, anything I am missing on Jenkins windows agent to configure? and also my shell scripts are not executing on cygwin when using the Jenkins, they are executing on windows command prompt, can someone please advise how to make the jenkins to use the cygwin terminalto execute shell scripts instead of command prompt? .Thank you.

Below is the Jenkins pipeline how I am calling test.sh(test.sh is on jenkins windows agent)

```
stage('Import') {
            
        steps {
        script {
              sh "/home/kumar/test.sh"
              }
              }
              }
```

I see below error when execute the build.

- /home/kumar/test.sh
  FIND: Invalid switch
  mv: cannot stat '/home/kumar/TEST_FILES/*': No such file or directory

below find command used in script.

```
find /cygdrive/d/Jenkins/workspace/sam-org/testing/app_name/src/abc -name "*.dsx" -exec cp "{}" /home/kumar/ITEST_FILES \
```

Comment: please clarify HOW you are running the script from Jenkins and what type of script ? I assume they are Bash script, so how are you telling Jenkis to run cygwin bash?

Comment: please see above pipeline for calling shell script, looks like script is not executing on cygwin(mintty), it is executing on windows command prompt